# Magento2 :Error while creating invoice programetically

Tags: magento2

I am trying to create invoice programmatically and always getting Error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bitnami_magento`.`sales_order_item`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_ITEM_ORDER_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `sales_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order_item` (`quote_item_id`, `store_id`, `product_id`, `product_type`, `product_options`, `weight`, `is_virtual`, `sku`, `name`, `description`, `applied_rule_ids`, `additional_data`, `is_qty_decimal`, `qty_backordered`, `qty_invoiced`, `qty_ordered`, `base_cost`, `price`, `base_price`, `original_price`, `base_original_price`, `tax_percent`, `tax_amount`, `base_tax_amount`, `tax_invoiced`, `base_tax_invoiced`, `discount_percent`, `discount_amount`, `base_discount_amount`, `discount_invoiced`, `base_discount_invoiced`, `row_total`, `base_row_total`, `row_invoiced`, `base_row_invoiced`, `row_weight`, `base_tax_before_discount`, `tax_before_discount`, `price_incl_tax`, `base_price_incl_tax`, `row_total_incl_tax`, `base_row_total_incl_tax`, `discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `discount_tax_compensation_invoiced`, `base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced`, `gift_message_id`, `gift_message_available`, `free_shipping`, `weee_tax_applied`, `weee_tax_applied_amount`, `weee_tax_applied_row_amount`, `weee_tax_disposition`, `weee_tax_row_disposition`, `base_weee_tax_applied_amount`, `base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt`, `base_weee_tax_disposition`, `base_weee_tax_row_disposition`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Here is my code for create invoice

```
class Invoice extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
/**
 * Create Invoice Based on Order Object
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
 * @return $this
 */
public function generateInvoice($orderId){
    try {
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if (!$order->getId()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The order no longer exists.'));
        }
        if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('The order does not allow an invoice to be created.')
                );
        }

        $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
        if (!$invoice) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We can\'t save the invoice right now.'));
        }
        if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('You can\'t create an invoice without products.')
            );
        }
        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
        $invoice->register();
        $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
        $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically INVOICED', false);
        $transactionSave = $this->transactionFactory->create()->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
        $transactionSave->save();

        // send invoice emails, If you want to stop mail disable below try/catch code
        try {
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t send the invoice email right now.'));
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $invoice;
}
```

**Anyone have idea what wrong inside my code or what is a reason for the error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is very close.

I think some logic is overlapping.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoInvoice/blob/99034f55aa757bf62b0b7d32a7c3aff3343bd012/Helper/AutoInvoice.php#L90-L122

```
    public function createInvoice($orderId)
    {
        try {
            $order = $this->getById($orderId);
            if (!$order || !$order->getId() || !$order->canInvoice() || !$order->getPayment()) {
                return;
            }

            // code removed

            $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
            if (!$invoice || !$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                return;
            }
            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
            $invoice->register();
            $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
            $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically INVOICED', false);
            $transactionSave = $this->transactionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addObject($invoice)
                ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
            $transactionSave->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // You might not want this
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```

Note: getById just loads order via \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface

```
    public function getById($orderId)
    {
        try {
            return $this->orderRepositoryInterface->get($orderId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try same but not wokring it giving me another error
"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Paypal\\Model\\Adminhtml\\Express\\Interceptor::isOrderAuthorizationAllowed() must be an instance of Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Payment, null given, called in vendor\/magento\/module-paypal\/Plugin\/OrderCanInvoice.php

Comment: I think this is a magento issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15406